# How to know if the called method is the last one

Tags: javascript

Having an object like this:

```
var foo = {
    a: function () {
       /*
          if (lastCall) {
             return this.b();
          }
        */
       ...
       return this;
    }
  , b: function () { return ...; }
};
```

How can I know, *inside* of the `a` method if the current `a` call is the last?

```
foo.a().a().a().a()
//              ^- This should return another value
//                 while the other calls return `this`
```

I know I can use a boolean value or something in the last call, but if possible, I would like to avoid that.

So, is it possible to check if the current call is the last one in the stack?

Comment: I guess you might need to use a global variable?

Comment: @PraveenKumar OP don't know how many times the method will be called, so using counter may not help

Comment: @Tushar Na, not for a counter, but well, a global variable might work in this case. I don't know. Still trying to think.

Comment: May I know the use-case? An example

Comment: @Tushar Sure: I want to call `this.toString()` in `b`, for convenience (instead of doing `foo.a().a().toString()` or `"" + foo.a().a()`). But there could be other applications as well.

Comment: The last method invoked must be an `a` method? Cannot be another method? For example: `foo.a().a().a().a().last()`? In this way you can insert the logic for the last invocation in the `last` method.

Comment: @Tushar No idea, thinking. `:P`

Comment: @Andrea Like I mentioned, I would like to handle that automatically. Just want to know if it's possible... :)

Comment: We could make a destructor function if possible. That will execute at the last, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @PraveenKumar What do you mean by *destructor function*?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Destructors get called at the end!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Like Andrea said? Maybe add an example.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Still thinking, or may be I am done with my thoughts. Let Tushar say something. He's a real Geek in JavaScript than me.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I think, you cannot do this. Let's take example of jQuery, the methods that returns anything than the jQuery object cannot be chained. So, the way could be passing a param to the last function that will distinguish it from other calls

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks, guys! Accepted Magus's answer. :)

Comment: I would suggest you to use recursion instead of chaining

Comment: @Tushar Well, I will not call only the `a` method. It's a library that colors the strings with ANSI characters. You could do: `Color("my text").red().blueBackground().toString()`.

Comment: @IonicăBizău `Color("my text").red().blueBackground().get()` sounds better than using `toString` for developers

Comment: @Tushar But using `toString()` is called when other strings are there: `console.log("Hello " + Color("World").blue())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in `a`, the next `a` is not called yet. So you can't know there will be an other call to `a` after this one.

You can get the stack with an `Error` object like this :

```
var stack = new Error().stack;
```

But the stack won't help you. The next call to `a` is not in the stack.

I'm pretty sure you can't do this without a syntax change like `foo.a().a().b();` or `foo.a().a().a(true);`.